# Adding Semicolons

Tags: code-golf

**Objective**

Write the shortest program possible that adds semicolons to the end of all lines of code in a file **unless**:

- it already has a semicolon at the end
- the line is blank.

Must be a complete program.

**Bonuses**

Write the program so it won't produce any compiler errors when running the program on a C Header File.

Comment: `for(;;)\n{\n/*whatever*/\n}` is going to produce some unexpected results :P

Comment: You can do some crazy things in C (especially with the help of the PP). To require it to work on any C header is a scope way beyond reasonable.

Comment: You say that the C Header File part is a bonus, but you don't specify how many bytes we get off for it.

Comment: Your challenge itself seems fine, but the bonus part is a tad underspecified. In what situations exactly should we append a semicolon to get the bonus? What is that bonus worth?

Comment: My recommendation is that you just take out that bonus part -- it'll be very difficult to specify it clearly and even then I suspect the only sane solution for the bonus part would be to just apply semicolons, compile and remove semi-colons until it doesn't break...

Answer (score 3):

## Retina, 12 bytes

```
m`[^;¶]$
$0;
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWBbXjvCtl0kCiQwOw&input=Zm9vOwpiYXIKCmJheg)

#### How it works

```
m`        Activate multi-line mode.
  [^;¶]   Match any character but a semicolon or a linefeed...
       $  followed by the end of the line.
$0        Replace the match with itself...
  ;       followed by a semicolon.
```

Comment: I count 13 bytes and 12 characters (¶ is two bytes)

Comment: @Loovjo In UTF-8, yes. ISO 8559-1 encodes ¶ as 0xB6.

Comment: Do we have a standard on encoding btw?

Comment: @Loovjo [Sort of.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5879)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>19</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
s/[^;]$/$&;/
```

[Try this fiddle online](http://ideone.com/fork/B36z25) or [this test suite.](http://ideone.com/fork/cKO4aX)

Must be run with the `-pl` flags; this is accounted for in the score.

Thanks to @manatwork for -4 bytes.

Comment: With one more option, the `-l`, can be reduced to `s/[^;]$/$&;/g`.

Comment: Ooh, thanks! I forgot about that option.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript ES6, 69 bytes

```js
alert(prompt().split`\\n`.map(x=>x.match(/;$|^$/g)?x:x+';').join`\n`)
```

In the input, separate the newlines by `\n`, e.g. `some;\ncode\nthere`

Comment: @man it doesn't seem to work properly... Though nice idea.